# EF Core 7.0.5 : relationships from parent property and child property to same entity

Tags: c#, insert, foreign-keys, change-tracking, ef-core-7.0

I have a model in which 4 classes (part of the complete model)

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public City? City { get; set; } //<--pay attention
}

public class Initiator
{   
    public int? SessionId{ get; set; }
    public Session? Session{ get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public City? City { get; set; } //<--pay attention
}

public class Session
{
    public int? SessionId { get; set; }
    public Customer? Customer { get; set; }    //<--pay attention   
    public City? City { get; set; }  //<--pay attention
    public Initiator? Initiator { get; set; } //<--pay attention
    //And more properties, some of them in Initiator structure 
    //- table splitting (tbl_session)
}
```

And the following tables:

tbl_session

```
id | customer_id | city_id | init_first_name | init_last_name | init_city_id
```

---

tbl_customer

```
id | first_name | last_name | city_id
```

---

tbl_city

```
city | city_desc
```

---

I built a `Context`:

```
public class EntityContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Initiator> Initiators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer("myConnectionString");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<City>(c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("tbl_city")
                 .HasKey(c => c.Id);
                c.Property(c => c.Id)
                 .HasColumnName("city");
                c.Property(c => c.Name)
                 .HasColumnName("city_desc");              
          }); 

        modelBuilder.Entity<Initiator>(c =>
          {                      
            c.ToTable("tbl_session")//<--pay attention - table splitting
                .HasKey(x => x.SessionId);                                 
            c.Property(c => c.FirstName)
                .HasColumnName("init_first_name");
            c.Property(c => c.LastName)
                .HasColumnName("init_last_name "); 
            c.HasOne(x => x.City)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("init_city_id");
          }  
    
        modelBuilder.Entity<Session>(c =>
          {
                c.ToTable("tbl_session")
                   .HasKey(c=>c.SessionId)
                   .HasDefaultValueSql();
                c.Property(c=>c.SessionId)
                   .HasColumnName("id");                
                c.HasOne(e => e.Customer)
                           .WithOne()
                           .HasForeignKey("customer_id");
                c.HasOne(e => e.City)
                           .WithOne()
                           .HasForeignKey("city_id");
                c.HasOne<Initiator>(x=>x.Initiator)
                           .WithOne(x => x.Session)
                           .HasForeignKey<Patient>(x => x.SessionId);
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(c =>
            {
                c.ToTable("tbl_customer")
                   .HasKey(c=>c.Id);                
                c.Property(c => c.Id)
                   .HasColumnName("id");
                c.Property(c => c.FirstName)
                   .HasColumnName("first_name");
                c.Property(c => c.LastName)
                   .HasColumnName("last_name");
            });
        }
}
```

The `Session` and the `Initiator` are mapped to `tbl_session`- [table splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting#table-splitting).
In the `Repository` I tried to get the `Session` list and to insert one new record.

I got the list successfully, but the adding failed even when the value in `City` was different. If the `City` in the `Session` or `Customer` is `null` the `Attach` and the `save` will succeed (different `foreignKeys` succeed).

```
public async Task<bool> InsertSession(Session newSession)
{
  var ent = _mainDBContext.Sessions.Attach(newSession);//<--failed
  ent.State = EntityState.Added;
  return await _mainDBContext.SaveChangesAsync()>0;

}
```

The error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'City' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.NullableKeyIdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable`1 fallbackState)

example for newSession values

```json
{
  "customer": {
    "id": 548,
    "firstName": "Nataly",
    "lastName": "Low",
    "city": {
      "id": 14589,
      "name": "New York"
    }
  },
  "city": {
    //can be also  "id": 14589,"name": "New York" and will fail
    "id": 756,
    "name": "Los Angeles"
  }
}
```

Comment: If Session and Customer both have the same City make sure it's also the same *instance*.

Comment: how did you create newUser?, if you had retrieved Cite from dbContext uses `_mainDBContext.Sessions.Entry(newUser)`

Comment: @GertArnold, `City` can be different because `Customer` can live in different `Session`'s `City` but also can be the same

Comment: @Laaziv, I got newSession (newUser) from Controller->Service->Repository function's parameter , it's new object which isn't in the list so why should i to use Entry function?

Comment: Sure, it was mainly about the *instances* of City objects. The example `newSession` won't fail. One with two same cities will.

Comment: @GertArnold, what should I do if the `Session` has been in the `Customer` `City`

Comment: You appear to be serialising your data model as your view model. This is an anti-pattern. You may be allowing the end user to create new `City` instances.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `Attach` and `Entry` is that `Attach` recursively analyzes the object and takes into account all related entities, while `Entry` only takes into account the object passed to the method and not its related entities. You can use these methods to modify the code as follows:

```cs
public async Task<bool> InsertSession(Session newSession)
{
  var ent = _mainDBContext.Sessions.Entry(newSession);
  ent.State = EntityState.Added;
  return await _mainDBContext.SaveChangesAsync()>0;
}
```

**Edited to add an answer to your second table splitting issue:**

**⚠️ Warning:**

> The provided configuration example for SplitToTable is not recommended as it is a misuse

It seems that you have not configured your entities to use SplitToTable. However, it is important to note that the provided configuration example is not recommended as it is a misuse of SplitToTable. That being said, the Entry method can be used to add an entity with the SplitToTable option.

```cs
[Table("tbl_city")]
public class City
{
    [Key]        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("city_desc")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; } = new List<Customer>();
}
public class CityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<City>
{
    void IEntityTypeConfiguration<City>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<City> builder)
    {
    }
}

[Table("tbl_customer")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //[Column("first_name")] 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    //[Column("last_name")] 
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual City City { get; set; } = null!; //<--pay attention

}
public class CustomerConfigue : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
    }
}
[Table("tbl_initiator")]
public class Initiator
{
    [Key]public int? SessionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(SessionId))] public virtual Session Session { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column("init_first_name")] public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    [Column("init_last_name")] public string? LastName { get; set; }
    [Column("init_city_id")] public int CityId { get; set; }
}
public class InitiatoConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Initiator>
{
    void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Initiator>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Initiator> builder)
    {
    }
}    
[Table("tbl_session")]
public class Session
{
    [Key]public int? SessionId { get; set; }
    [Column("customer_id")] public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] public string? FirstName { get => Customer.FirstName; set => _ = value; }
    [NotMapped] public string? LastName { get => Customer.LastName; set => _ = value; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CustomerId))] public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column("city_id")] public int CityId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] public int CityId1 { get => City.Id; set => _ = value; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(CityId))]
    public virtual City City { get; set; } = null!;
}
public class SessionConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Session>
{
    void IEntityTypeConfiguration<Session>.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Session> builder)
    {
        builder.SplitToTable<Session>("tbl_initiator", buildAction =>
        {
            buildAction.Property(e => e.FirstName).HasColumnName("init_first_name");
            buildAction.Property(e => e.LastName).HasColumnName("init_last_name");
            buildAction.Property(e => e.CityId1).HasColumnName("init_city_id");
        }
        );
        builder.HasOne(e => e.Customer).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
```

configuration DbContext

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(ExempleTestDbContext).Assembly);
}
```

Comment: your answer is right, but it doesn't solve my problem completely. Since `Session` is also [split table model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting#table-splitting) and this relationship will also be ignored (not just the regular `foreignKey`).

Comment: @Ron No, the relationship would not be ignored. EF will make primary key relationships with navigation properties. If the city ID does not exist, an exception will be raised.

Comment: @Ron You will see that the registration on the basis of done is correct. Please do it test to see

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough, as I written your answer is right, but not for split table, I will add some code in the question

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is. could you add an update to your question about unwanted behavior after using `Entry`

Comment: I edited the code up in the question - pay attention to class `Initiator`. When I am using the `Entry` function the columns of `Initiator` are staying empty.

Comment: @Ron To try `ent.References.ToList().ForEach(e => { if( e.TargetEntry == #Cite || e.TargetEntry == #Customer  )  e.TargetEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged; });` used the Attach method replaces #cite and #Customer, I forget what it should correspond to

Comment: @Ron
```csharp
public async Task<bool> InsertSession(Session newSession)
{
    var ent = _mainDBContext.Sessions.Attach(newSession);
    ent.State = EntityState.Added;
    var entCite = _mainDBContext.Entry(newSession.City);
    var entCustomer = _mainDBContext.Entry(newSession.Customer);
    ent.References.ToList().ForEach(e => { if (e.TargetEntry == entCite || e.TargetEntry == entCustomer) e.TargetEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged; });
    return await _mainDBContext.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer about _used the Attach method replaces #cite and #Customer, I forget what it should correspond to_, and the answer with the full function code not work because the failure is in the `Attach` function as you can see in the code remark above

Comment: @Ron Hi, look at my last comment I indicated what is #City, please open another post for your split table problem and refer to this post ps:(a small thumb  (voted) would be desirable)

Comment: My reputation is too low for voting - I can only mark the right answer, and I didn't understand your comment, can you add another answer with this code with explanation?

Comment: @Ron ok I'll post a new answer, just give me time to do some tests

Comment: @Ron I added an update to my response.